# VS2019 IDE and command line compiler disagree on C# statements

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

So in the IDE I have the following:

```
    public static void ConnectToOperaObjects(ref Microsoft.ClearScript.Windows.JScriptEngine jSE)
    {
        foreach (Tuple<string, object> tso in new List<Tuple<string, object>>() {
            (name: "CSOperaDriver", type: typeof(OpenQA.Selenium.Opera.OperaDriver)),
            (name: "CSOperaDriverService", type: typeof(OpenQA.Selenium.Opera.OperaDriverService)),
            (name: "CSOperaOptions", type: typeof(OpenQA.Selenium.Opera.OperaOptions)) })
        {
            jSE.AddHostType(tso.name, tso.type);
        }
    }
```

The IDE compiles it without question. The command line compiler complains with

```
Objects.cs(161,17): error CS1950: The best overloaded Add method 'List<Tuple<string, object>>.Add(Tuple<string, object>)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments [C:\Users\bugma\Source\Repos\RR\RR\RR.csproj]
Objects.cs(161,17): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from '(string, System.Type)' to 'Tuple<string, object>' [C:\Users\bugma\Source\Repos\RR\RR\RR.csproj]
Objects.cs(162,17): error CS1950: The best overloaded Add method 'List<Tuple<string, object>>.Add(Tuple<string, object>)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments [C:\Users\bugma\Source\Repos\RR\RR\RR.csproj]
Objects.cs(162,17): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from '(string, System.Type)' to 'Tuple<string, object>' [C:\Users\bugma\Source\Repos\RR\RR\RR.csproj]
Objects.cs(163,17): error CS1950: The best overloaded Add method 'List<Tuple<string, object>>.Add(Tuple<string, object>)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments [C:\Users\bugma\Source\Repos\RR\RR\RR.csproj]
Objects.cs(163,17): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from '(string, System.Type)' to 'Tuple<string, object>' [C:\Users\bugma\Source\Repos\RR\RR\RR.csproj]
Objects.cs(165,42): error CS1061: 'Tuple<string, object>' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no accessible extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'Tuple<string, object>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\bugma\Source\Repos\RR\RR\RR.csproj]
Objects.cs(165,52): error CS1061: 'Tuple<string, object>' does not contain a definition for 'type' and no accessible extension method 'type' accepting a first argument of type 'Tuple<string, object>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\bugma\Source\Repos\RR\RR\RR.csproj]
```

The command line tool is invoked as

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" %* /t:Build
```

with RR's `csproj` file as the argument. I have tried providing it the `sln` file instead, but to no effect.

What's the fix?

Comment: Instead of editing the post, id suggest creating a self answer, seems more useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be changing your `Tuple` to the following *Named* `ValueTuple` C# 7 Syntax, and it should work:

```
var list = new List<(string name, object type)>()
          {
             (name: "CSOperaDriver", type: typeof(OpenQA.Selenium.Opera.OperaDriver))
             ...
          };

foreach (var tso in list)
   ...
```

or changing your intializer like so

```
new Tuple<string, object>( "CSOperaDriver",  typeof(OpenQA.Selenium.Opera.OperaDriver))),
```

My *spidey senses* tells me `Tuple` with the *Named* `ValueTuple` Syntax is causing you the problem.

Comment: I just had some success with changing the foreach clause to `var tso in new[] { ...`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @TheGeneral for suggesting the change to `ValueTuple`. Interestingly, the type didn't like being an object and insisted on being a `System.Type`.

```
    public static void ConnectToOperaObjects(ref Microsoft.ClearScript.Windows.JScriptEngine jSE)
    {
        foreach (var tso in new List<(string name, System.Type type)>() {
            ("CSOperaDriver", typeof(OpenQA.Selenium.Opera.OperaDriver)),
            ("CSOperaDriverService", typeof(OpenQA.Selenium.Opera.OperaDriverService)),
            ("CSOperaOptions", typeof(OpenQA.Selenium.Opera.OperaOptions)) })
        {
            AddHostType(ref jSE, tso.name, tso.type);
        }
    }
```

There is an another alternative, which is to change the foreach clause to

```
foreach (var tso in new[] {
```

This creates an implicit array and encourages the compiler to figure out what the elements are.